# Any word for the sound of ripple?

Tags: single-word-requests

Here is what, I am in dire need of a single word, that denotes a meaning of the sound pertaining to ripple.

Explicitly asking, is there any word for the sound produced when a drop of water hits on the surface of large body of water?

Comment: There would not be that much of a sound from a single drop. A plop? Check out this  poem: http://examples.yourdictionary.com/5-examples-of-onomatopoeia.html Not the best admittedly, but still....

Comment: Also note, that a ripple occurs ***after*** the plop and ripples are soundless. If they are big enough to be termed waves then they might make a sound as they break.

Comment: @Jim: I appreciate your comment here.

Answer (score 2):

It's **[Plop](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plop)**.

> 1. a sound like something dropping into water.

Definition of plop (verb) by Merriam Webster:

> 1. to fall, drop, or move suddenly with a sound like that of something dropping into water.

Answer (score 1):

**[Drip](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drip)**

> the sound made by or as if by falling drops

*She heard the drip of water hitting the lake's surface*